# jquery clone function nested delete option

Tags: jquery, clone

My demo, is really clear, when I clone my element
I clone and delete the divs however, the :last element (li) should't been removed. 
what I'm missing?

is something to do with this!:

```
$(document).on("click", 'li.delete',function () {
            $(this).closest(".outerDiv").remove();
    if ($(this).is(".outerDiv:last")){
            return false;
    }
```

**DEMO:**
http://jsfiddle.net/XeELs/86/

**JQUERY**
    var cloneCount = 0;
    $("#add-address").click(function() {

```
    $("#to-add-address").clone()
        .attr("id", "to-add-address_Clone" + cloneCount)
        .insertAfter("#to-add-address");
    $("#clone", "#to-add-address_Clone" + cloneCount)
        .attr("id", "clone_Clone" + cloneCount);
    cloneCount++;
});

$(document).on("click", '.options li a',function () {
            $(this).closest(".options").find('li a').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');

        });
$(document).on("click", 'li.delete',function () {
            $(this).closest(".outerDiv").remove();
    if ($(this).is(".outerDiv:last")){
            return false;
    }
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
var cloneCount = 0;
$("#add-address").click(function() {

    $("#to-add-address").clone()
        .attr("id", "to-add-address_Clone" + cloneCount)
        .insertAfter("#to-add-address").addClass('cloned');  //add a new class cloned to the cloned outerDivs
    $("#clone", "#to-add-address_Clone" + cloneCount)
        .attr("id", "clone_Clone" + cloneCount);
    cloneCount++;
});

$(document).on("click", '.options li a',function () {
            $(this).closest(".options").find('li a').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');

        });
$(document).on("click", 'li.delete',function () {
            $(this).closest(".outerDiv").filter('.cloned').remove(); // and delete only the cloned ones
    if ($(this).is(".outerDiv:last")){
            return false;
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [size()](http://api.jquery.com/size/) method to find out how many address blocks there are, this will let you delete them until there is only one left:

```
$(document).on("click", 'li.delete',function () {

    if ($('.outerDiv').size() > 1){
            $(this).closest(".outerDiv").remove();
    }

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2mby5/